# RFT click on second named node

Tags: rft

I have a JTree that has two same-named nodes.
I am writing an RFT script that needs to click the second-named node but it will only click the first entry it finds.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAbvx.png)
By utilising ITestDataTree, I have managed to retrieve the ITestDataTreeNode I need but can't figure out how to click it.
Is there any way to convert an ITestDataTreeNode object into a GuiTestObject?

Thanks in advance,
Steven.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

simple as:

```
        List list = new List();

        list.append(new Index(0)); // root
        list.append(new Index(0)); // suite
        list.append(new Index(0)); // scenario
        list.append(new Index(0)); // testcase
        list.append(new Index(1)); // action

        jTree().click(list); // expands second action node
```